# Semantically, how does 'before' differ from 'till'?

Tags: etymology, differences, historical-change, till-until

> [**till** {prep. [here]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/202001#eid18426550)  <s>conj., and adv.</s>}
>
> Etymology: [..] Probably originally a noun * *til* = Old English *till* fixed point, station [...]
>   hence the const. with genitive: prop. ‘with the limit or goal of (the place or time named)’.  [...]
>   To the same root belong Old English *til* adjective ‘to the purpose, serviceable, good’ [...]
>
> II. Of time.
>   [5] b. After a negative, denoting the continuance of the negative condition up to the time indicated (and implying its cessation then); thus **nearly** equivalent to *before*.  Cf. [B. 1b.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/202001#eid18426550)

OED's use of the adverb **nearly** above, implies difference(s) between **till** and *before*. So what are these semantic drifts?
Please expose and explain them.

Etymologically, **till** means: TO some fixed point or station. So this 'TO' can be interpreted as approximation to the fixed point/station, without knowing whether the fixed point is attained. Which meanings of *before*, does this interpretation of **till** neglect?

Comment: It is not "semantically" but *logically* and *mathematically*. This question is relevant for any language, not just English.

Answer (score 1):

> I'll be here till 3.
>
> I'm going to leave before 3.

I hope I understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the two words are more or less interchangeable, but they do have subtle differences.

> **before**
>
> *preposition*
>
> previous to; earlier or sooner than

*Source: Dictionary.com*

> **until**
>
> *conjunction*
>
> up to the time that or when; till

*Source: Dictionary.com*